# Pass Javascript variable into Django tag

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

as the title says I'm trying to replace a value in my Django tag with a Javascript variable. I'm not sure if it's even possible but here is what I have (The tag is between ``):

```
const myTemplate = (list) => html`
<form method="post" class="notes-form">
   {%  csrf_token %}
   {{ user.profile|meet_notes:15 }}
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
`
```

I would like to replace the 15 by a variable like `${list.met_profile.id}` for exemple (this tag will render an input with a value of this variable, here 15).

Thank you!

Comment: you can not do it directly , you will need to write some javascript code for it.

Comment: That's what I expected, but I've been trying since a while and even throught Javascript I did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

put the following code in your HTML document

```
<span id="change_val">abc</span>
<script>
    const ele = document.getElementById("change_val")
    ele.innerText = 15
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use a serializer instead of a template tag. the django template tag will run before the js so this is not ideal.